# Automorphism of the matrix algebra is an inner automorphism

Tags: modules, algebras

How can I find an elementary proof for Skolem Noether's theorem which says that every algebra automorphism of the matrix algebra $M_n(K)$ is an inner automorphism.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496620/wikipedia-proof-of-skolem-noether-theorem)

Comment: You could look in books or try an internet search. (straight face)

Comment: @math137 yes, I've seen that, but I would need a proof for the general case, with K a field, not Complex numbers.

Comment: Try page 75 of [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0m-JMAEACAAJ&dq=finite+dimensional+algebras+drozd&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gqVgVNbiC8zbPamOgLgM&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA)

Comment: A bit late to the party, but this arXiv link seems to be what you were looking for:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08368