# Prove that an automorphism of $M_n(k)$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field must be an inner automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Prove that an automorphism of $M_n(k)$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field must be an inner automorphism. I'm a bit stuck on this one but I feel like I understand why it's true. Since $M_n(k)$ has a unique simple module (a column of lentgh $n$) really the only thing that can be done is to permute around the order of these simple summands (from a vector space perspective) but we need to leave them in their original order so we have to undo this. This would lead us to conjugation by an invertible matrix. Can someone provide some guidance please? Thanks!

There is a relevant post here but I was hoping to avoid looking up the proof and just receive some guidance on how to continue.

[Automorphism of the matrix algebra is an inner automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009843/automorphism-of-the-matrix-algebra-is-an-inner-automorphism)

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of the *Skolem-Noether* theorem. You are thinking along the right lines. If $\phi:M_n(k)\to M_n(k)$ is a $k$-automorphism, and $S$ is a simple module
(say the column vectors), then it is also a simple module for the "twisted" action
$(v,A)\mapsto v\phi(A)$. So the conventional $M_n(k)$-module structure is isomorphic to the
new one. Therefore there is a $k$-linear map $\theta:S\to S$ with
$$\theta(vA)=\theta(v)\phi(A).$$
Can you show that $\theta$ induces an appropriate inner automorphism of $M_n(k)$?