# Simple Functional Equation about Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries. Find all functions $f:V \rightarrow V $that satisfy below conditions:
1)$f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$
2)$f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$
3)$f(I_{n\times n})=I_{n\times n}$
for every $A,B\in V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three conditions say precisely that $f$ is a ring homomorphism from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to itself. The center of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ consists of the scalar matrices, which we may identify with $\mathbb{R}$. Since any homomorphism $f$ maps the center of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ into itself, $f$ induces a field automorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which must be the identity (since $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{R})$ is trivial). Therefore, $f$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra endomorphism of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Since $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is simple, $f$ must be injective, hence $f$ is an automorphism since $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. The Skolem-Noether theorem implies that $f$ must be an inner automorphism, i.e., it must have the form $f(A) = SAS^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $S$.

Comment: can you please tell another solution for this problem because I'm not familiar with definitions of Ring and ... .

Comment: I'm don't see a way to prove this result without using some theory about rings. However, at least the conclusion should be understandable even if you're not familiar with rings; you should be able to check, for instance, that any function of the form $f(A)=SAS^{-1}$ satisfies the three conditions given, even if it's not easy to see why these are the only possible $f$.

Comment: @user26857, I've updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get it: why a homomorphism maps the center into itself?

Comment: @user26857, You're right; there's still a problem. Let me see if I can figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know if there are any endomorphisms of $M_n(\mathbb R)$ which are not surjective?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496620/wikipedia-proof-of-skolem-noether-theorem (The result holds for any field.)