# Reference Quest for Skolem-Noether-Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules, algebras

What are good references for the Skolem-Noether theorem. I have to write about it so i would like to read a lot of proofs of this theorem. I only had two linear and two abstract algebra courses.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) for references (e.g., Falko Lorenz). See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496620/wikipedia-proof-of-skolem-noether-theorem) for its proof.

Comment: Thank you. I will look for the wikipedia-references when im back at my university. But i thougt there could be more refernces.

Comment: Take the duplicate. There is already a proof given. You can also search online for lecture notes; there are really many having Skolem-Noether online.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book by P M Cohn ALGEBRA  in two volumes. The second volume treats this topic,  Brauer Groups etc. It is a well-written book, and has references to relevant research articles which you do not normally in  books of that level.

For exmaple in Field theory he gives proof of Luroth's theorem on simple transcendental extensions and stated that this is false when trans. degree is more than 1 and gave references to research articles giving counter examples.